# Is $A=\{ (x,y)|x>0, 0<x^2 + y^2<5\}$ an open set in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

I know, if let say we omit the term "$x>0$" in set A , called it A', we can apply the theorem "a criterion for a continuity mappings in terms of Open sets" we can define $f:R^2 \to R$

$f(x,y)= x^2 + y^2$

then since $f$ is Polynomial then it's continous and we know that $(0,\infty)$ is open set on R so we can conclude that $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ which is the set A' is open .Firstly, what do they mean by taking inverses $f^{-1}$ , it does not even one to one function for example the image 1 in R can be belongs to $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ in $R^2$.

And also i am doubt wheter we can do the same thing for the set A ? because we have some restriction in there (i.e $x>0$). Can someone explain ? my guess is cannot, since it does not even one to one function for example the image 1 in R can be belongs to $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ in $R^2$ . And $(-1,0)$ is the outside of set $A$.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the title? Or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

At any rate, here is a helpful fact: the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open (think about why). Since $\{(x,y): x>0\}$ (or $(x,y,z)$, if you meant $\mathbb{R}^3$) is open this will complete your proof.

Comment: $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is the preimage and you can always find it. In this case $f(x,y)$ is a paraboloid. $A$ is an open set because it is the interection of two open sets.

Comment: @Glare ,  i mean $R^2$

Comment: That's obviously open. Why not? Can you find any point, where you can't find a small enough disk to be contained in the set?

Comment: I know it's open but my question is can we do the similar method as what i ve done to show the set A' is open?

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, what do they mean by taking inverses $f^{-1}$

$f^{-1}$ does not always refer to the inverse of a function. For any function $f:A\to B$, and any set $C\subseteq B$, the set $f^{-1}(C)$ (called the "preimage" of $C$" is defined as $$\{a\in A| f(a)\in C\}$$

this definition is valid even if $f$ is not invertible.

> And also i am doubt wheter we can do the same thing for the set A

Sort of. You can define $A_1=\{(x,y)| x>0\}$ and $A_2=\{(x,y)|0<x^2+y^2<5\}$.

Then, if you define $f_1$ as $f_1(x,y)=x$, and $f_2$ as $f_2(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, then it is relatively easy to show:

- $A_1=f^{-1}((0,\infty))$, therefore, $A_1$ is open.
- $A_2=f^{-1}((0,5))$, therefore, $A_2$ is open.
- $A=A_1\cap A_2$, therefore, $A$ is open.

Comment: Why we cant directly define $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $is continous then we know that $(0,5)$ is open set then $f^{-1} (0,5)$ is open which is the set A ,so A is open., what's wrong with this method?

Comment: @BREYSKS $f^{-5}$ is not $A$. For example, $(-2, 0)\in f^{-5}$ (because $f(-2,0)=4\in(0,5)$, but $(-2, 0)\notin A$ (because $-2>0$ is not true).

Answer (score 0):

As comments have suggested, the method used to demonstrate that the set is open depends on what methods that either:

- you have been taught are valid
- you are comfortable using.

Let $S$ denote the set of all $(x,y)$ where:

- $x > 0$
- $x^2 + y^2 < 5$.

Then, the most basic method is to take any element $s$ in $S$ and explicitly construct the neighborhood $N$ around this element $s$ such that $N \subseteq S.$

Here, I am assuming that you are accustomed to regarding an open circle of a fixed positive radius $R$ around a point $(x_1,y_1)$ as a neighborhood $N$ around the point $(x_1,y_1)$.

So: for any $(x_1,y_1)$ in $S$:

Let $a = (x_1/2)$. 
Choose $b$ to be any (small) positive real number such that 
$\displaystyle \frac{5 - x_1^2 - y_1^2}{2} + x_1^2 > (x_1 + b)^2$ 
and 
$\displaystyle \frac{5 - x_1^2 - y_1^2}{2} + y_1^2 > (y_1 + b)^2$.
This will imply that $(x_1 + b)^2 + (y_1 + b)^2 < 5.$

Let $R = \min(a,b) \implies R > 0$.

Now, consider the subset of $S$ given by 
the set $T$ equal to the set
$x_1 - R < x < x_1 + R$ and $y_1 - R < y < y_1 + R.$

Then, the set $T$ is clearly a rectangular shape that is a subset of $S$.

So, consider the open circle, of radius $R$ around the point $(x_1,y_1)$.  This open circle is clearly a subset of $T$, which is a subset of $S$.

So, given any point $s = (x_1,y_1) \in S,$ a neighborhood $N$ centered around $(x_1,y_1)$, with a positive radius $R$ has been constructed, such that $N \subseteq S$.

Therefore, any element $s \in S$ is an interior point in $S$.

Therefore, the set $S$ is an open set, because all of its elements are interior points.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R.$ And $(0,5)$ is open in $\Bbb R.$ So $B=f^{-1}(0,5)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2.$

The function $g(x,y)=x$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R.$ And $\Bbb R^+$ is open in $\Bbb R.$ So $C=g^{-1}(\Bbb R^+)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2.$

So $A=B\cap C$ is the intersection of two open sets, so $A$ is open.

Comment: Why we cant directly define $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$is continous then we know that$ (0,5)$ is open set then $f^{−1}(0,5)$ is open which is the set A ,so A is open., what's wrong with this method?

Comment: @BREYSKS $f^{-5}$ is not $A$. For example, $(-2, 0)\in f^{-5}$, but $(-2, 0)\notin A$.

Comment: @5xum. Thank you for your comment addressed to the proposer. But you meant $f^{-1}(0,5)$, not $f^{-5}.$.... To the proposer: Note that there are two conditions to be met for $(x,y)$ to be in $A$: that $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(0,5)$ and $x>0$.